# On input change, get all input values in div and update label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="filters">

    <div class="filter-label">6</div>

    <div class="filter-inputs">

        <input type="number" name="i1" id="i1" value="1" min="0" step="1" />
        <input type="number" name="i2" id="i2" value="2" min="0" step="1" />
        <input type="number" name="i3" id="i3" value="3" min="0" step="1" />

    </div>

</div>
```

> ***The question:***
>
> I'd like to, when any input is changed, I want to get that value and
>   the value of the other two text boxes and add them all together. Once
>   I have the total value, I need to then change the text of the label
>   with the new value.

I also have the following JavaScript (jQuery) to detect when a change has happened, but after that, I can't figure out how to loop through each input in the div and get the value.

```
$('.filter .filter-inputs input').on('input', function() {

    var element = $(this);

    // ...

});
```

I looked at loops like the jQuery `each` method but I've got no idea how to loop through each input inside the `filter-inputs` div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create array from inputs using `map` and `get` methods and then calculate sum with `reduce` method.

```js
let inputs = $('.filters input');
let label = $('.filter-label');

inputs.on('input', function() {
  let sum = inputs.map(function() {
    return $(this).val()
  }).get().reduce((r, e) => r + +e, 0);

  label.text(sum)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  <div class="filter-label">6</div>
  <div class="filter-inputs">
    <input type="number" name="i1" id="i1" value="1" min="0" step="1" />
    <input type="number" name="i2" id="i2" value="2" min="0" step="1" />
    <input type="number" name="i3" id="i3" value="3" min="0" step="1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you could just create array with `Array.from` method and then use `reduce` method to sum values.

```js
let inputs = $('.filters input');
let label = $('.filter-label');

inputs.on('input', function() {
  label.text(Array.from(inputs).reduce((r, {value}) => r + +value, 0))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  <div class="filter-label">6</div>
  <div class="filter-inputs">
    <input type="number" name="i1" id="i1" value="1" min="0" step="1" />
    <input type="number" name="i2" id="i2" value="2" min="0" step="1" />
    <input type="number" name="i3" id="i3" value="3" min="0" step="1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to specify that the input is of type number let inputs = $('.filters input[type="number"]');

Answer (score 0):

No problem!

```
$('.filter .filter-inputs input').on('input', function() {

    //not needed:
    //var element = $(this);

    // Obtain numeric entries
    var i1 = Number($("#i1").val());
    var i2 = Number($("#i2").val());
    var i3 = Number($("#i3").val());

    // Calculate sum of entries
    var total = i1 + i2 + i3;

    // Populate label div with sum
    $(".filter-label").html(String(total));
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: you should explain your code so OP understands the issue

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated my answer with explanatory comments

Answer (score 0):

Use this script

```
$('.filter-inputs input').change(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.filter-inputs input').each(function(){

        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

   $('.filter-label').html(total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this task http://jsfiddle.net/72e3jLc0/

```
  let label = document.querySelector('.filter-label');
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-inputs input');
  inputs.forEach(input => {
      input.addEventListener('change', e => {
          label.innerText = parseInt(label.innerText) + parseInt(input.value);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total=0;
  $("input[type='number']").change(function() {
    $(".results").html("");
    var objects = $(".filters").find("input[type='number']");
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
      total += parseInt($(objects[i]).val());
    }
    $(".filter-label").text(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">

  <div class="filter-label">6</div>

  <div class="filter-inputs">

    <input type="number" name="i1" id="i1" value="1" min="0" step="1" />
    <input type="number" name="i2" id="i2" value="2" min="0" step="1" />
    <input type="number" name="i3" id="i3" value="3" min="0" step="1" />

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old thread, but I would like to give my contribution.

The id can be replaced with *document* or *"body"*, and *input* is not necessary if all your inputs have the class *.form-control.*

```
$("#id-of-overall-div-element").on("change", "input, .form-control", function () {
            // Do something     
});
```

Comment: I think this does not fully answer the question, the part OP was asking about specifically was how to access *all inputs in the parent container* when *one of them changes*. This is a valid suggestion on how to add events to all inputs in the container, but it doesn't show how to access their values.